# I want users not to be able to hand out higher privileges than they have themselves

Tags: discord.js

A moderator who has `manage_roles` permissions can even give the owner role to anyone. Is there a way that it can give out no higher role than to his own role?

So if he is admin, he can give at most admin, so not everyone can give random roles to anyone.

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../../configs/config.json');

module.exports = {
  config: {
    name: "give-roles",
  },
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
         message.delete();
         if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) return message.channel.send({
          embed: {
            title: `You dont have permission to use this command`
          }
        })

        if (!args[0] || !args[1]) return message.channel.send({
          embed: {
            title: "Incorrect usage, It's `<username || user id> <role name || id>"
          }
        })

        try {

             const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
             const roleName = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => (r.name === args[1].toString()) || (r.id === args[1].toString().replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')));

             const alreadyHasRole = member._roles.includes(roleName.id);

             if (alreadyHasRole) return message.channel.send({
          embed: {
            title: "User already has the role defined"
          }
        })
        
             const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                 .setTitle(`Role Name: ${roleName.name}`)
                 .setDescription(`${message.author} has successfully given the role ${roleName} to ${member.user}`)
                 .setColor('f3f3f3')
                 .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                 .setFooter(new Date().toLocaleString())

            return member.roles.add(roleName).then(() => message.channel.send(embed));
        } catch (e) {
            return message.channel.send({
          embed: {
            title: "Try to give a role that exists next time"
          }
        })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're able to use `roles.highest.position`:

```
let taggedMember = ... //(guildMember)
if (message.member.roles.highest.position < taggedMember.roles.highest.position) {
     //code...
}
```

Docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=highest